# Stripped-down Magento as a framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I've been working with Magento for a while now and really enjoy developing modules for it.  Lately I've been wondering if it's possible/feasible to strip out the ecommerce aspect and use the core components as an application framework, similar to ZF or CakePHP.

For example, inside /app/code/core/, everything except the following would be removed:

- Mage/Adminhtml
- Mage/Admin
- Mage/Core
- (I might be missing a couple other important pieces)
- All Varien and Zend code would also remain intact.

You would be able to develop custom web applications while taking advantage of support for:

- Modules
- Blocks, layouts, and templates
- Backend with users, permissions, and configuration
- Mage static methods to getModel, etc
- Translations
- Web services

Is this feasible or even a good idea?

Comment: Now that question has been asked, answered. We are considering an ecomm application and Magento is on the list. I've heard nothing but good things about it, so I wanted to ask you, what is your experience with Magneto? Would you recommend?

Comment: I highly recommend Magento.  In my opinion, it is by far the best e-commerce platform out there.

Comment: I completely agree.  Magento is a fantastic platform with a ton of useful features.  Developing new features is also a nice experience, but there is a bit of a learning curve (totally worth it though).

Comment: @ColinO'Dell (and @seanbreeden): Thanks guys. Seals the deal as far as I am concerned. Just curious, you guys use community or enterprise editions?

Comment: I develop for all platforms (CE, PE, EE and Go).  I like them all.

Comment: @MikePurcell, I develop for CE, PE and EE.  They all share the same core features.  PE and EE offer extras like gift cards, gift wrapping options, etc.  Go with whichever version has the features you need

Comment: I'm curious @ColinO'Dell, did you end up going with Magento?  How do you like it?

Comment: @seanbreeden no, I didn't.  I had a couple projects in mind when asking this question, one of which would integrate heavily with Magento and would've been a good fit - this project was not undertaken though.  The other was a custom web app, and we chose Symfony2 for that project - the Magento platform was just too verbose and restrictive for what we needed.  I love SF2 and will likely stick with that for future projects.

Comment: I've been getting into SF2 myself.  I still like Magento though! Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colin Mollenhour has something along these lines already:

https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-lite

Thanks to Vinai Kopp for telling me about this during the XDevCamp at the 2011 Magento Innovate Conference! :)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been envisioning, thanks for the link!

Comment: Interesting, this brings lots of possibilities. But I can't help wonder how likely is Colin Mollenhour to keep this up to date with official code? Would you rely on him and his project as the basis for your own application in the long term? I would want reassurance that bug fixes get passed on rapidly.

Comment: @clockworkgeek, that's a good question.  Luckily he's hosting the code on Github which makes it easy for anyone to make their own changes if he doesn't.  He can choose to merge them in if he wants.  If he doesn't and somebody else starts maintaining their own copy, you could use their updated codebase instead.  That is the beauty of open-source code.  Personally I wouldn't mind having to update it if I were to use it in a project.

Answer (score 3):

There have been rumors of this being done. Given that the idea is academically interesting and that the possibility exists, I mention it whenever I teach the Magento U Fundamentals of Magento Development course.

Magento *is* fundamentally an MVC app framework with eCommerce components. I first heard this idea at Magento's Imagine conference in 2011. [Alan Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4668/alan-storm) mentioned this during the developer track or the developer un-conference. I liked the notion immediately.

In addition to the items you cited, one would need to include `Mage_Eav` if one were going to require Magento-style EAV entity modeling and attribute management. `Mage_Page` would also be a strong candidate for inclusion if one were used to that module's handling of various page elements.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ben!  It looks like such a framework already exists (see @seanbreeden's link above).